# CodeIgniter passing dynamic data from controller to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am passing an array to a view from a controller. Simple stuff. Should work, but is behaving rather too strangely and I cannot figure out the bug.

This is the controller-

```
$link = "http://" . $server . ".something.com/uploads/" . $name;
$data = array(
    'name' =>$name,
    'server'=>$server,
    'link'=>$link,
    'username'=>$username
    );
$this->load->view('photo_edit', $data); //sending $data to view
```

This is the view -

```
<img src = "<?php echo $link; ?>"/>
```

When the view loads, the `$link` is just this - `http://.something.com/uploads/`
But when I echo the $link in the controller, its totally fine (with both the `$server` and `$name` showing correctly). There is some issue with passing the `$link`.

Comment: Are you doing any input validation to make sure `server` isn't empty?

Comment: The code as presented should work so obviously the problem is somewhere other than the code you posted.

Comment: What does a `print $link;` *inside the controller*? Is the variable set correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add $link to your $data array so the view can see it.

Do this instead:
$data['link'] = "http://" . $server . ".something.com/uploads/" . $name;

Comment: I am already adding $link to $data array, as in the code above. Though I tried your way, but still it does not work. Can there be any issue with whats the source of $server and $name? They are values that I receive from $this->input->post('server'); and $this->input->post('name'); 
Still not sure whats the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to double check the incoming values of those post variables. Make sure your form is passing them correctly too.

Comment: This should have been added as a comment underneath your original answer :).

Answer (score 0):

the problem is somewhere else, the code is right.
check if `$server` and `$name` are empty.